# Get variable data from database and display in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I want to pass value from inputbox data in php, and its display but php sql not recognize

```
<form name="form1"/>
<input type="text" name="code1" value="D50" size="7" maxlength="10" onblur="chkidpro(this.value,'provider1');" />
<input type="text" name="code2" value="" size="7" maxlength="10"/>
<form/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jvalue = form1.code1.value;

<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?> 

</script>

<?PHP 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc_one","pass");
mysql_select_db("abc_one", $con);

echo $abc;// ITS PRINT AS D50

$c = 'D50';

//$c = $abc;

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmycode where code='$c';");

$tab = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

if($result2 === false)

{
die("Database Error");
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0)

{
die("No Record Found");
}
```

**echo $abc; print AS D50**

**IF I REPLACE $c = $abc; NO RECORD FOUND**

**IF I REPLACE  $c = 'D50'; RECORD AVAILABLE**

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: try echoing the length of $abc to diagnose, there might be nulls or other white space.. if so trim it...

Comment: please specify what is not working or where you got stuck  ?

Comment: You can not mix JavaScript and PHP that way.

Comment: Please edit your question so it actually is a... question.

Comment: echo $abc;// ITS PRINT AS D50  that can not be true you just set it to : "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"

Comment: `echo $abc;` should not print `D50` please give more information also you missed semi column here `<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>`

Answer (score 3):

The code you show is working at the SERVER side so:

```
 <?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>
```

Sets `$abc` to `"<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"`

The javaScript you wrote there will work on the CLIENT side, the browser. Do not mix them...

Ok to clarify what is happening:

This text is in your server in a php file so when invoked:

```
Line                                       Action on Server
<form name="form1"/>                       //->sent to client
<input type="text" name="code1" value="D50"//->sent to client
<input type="text" name="code2" value=""   //->sent to client
<form/>                                    //->sent to client 
<script type="text/javascript">            //->sent to client
var jvalue = form1.code1.value;            //->sent to client(will run on client) 

<?php                                      //->php takes control on server

 $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"; //php runs this on server 
 //php sets $abc to "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>" on server...
 //php does not process javascript, php sees it as text...

?>                                         //->ends php control

</script>                                  //->sent to client

<?PHP                                      //->php takes control on server again

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc_one","pass"); // php runs this on server
mysql_select_db("abc_one", $con);                   // php runs this on server

echo $abc;                                          // php echoes $abc
```

Meaning that a line containing

```
<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>
```

**Is sent to client.**

It is written into your client document...

It will be evaluated on Client computer not on Server.

And it will happen in near future, not yet....

Why do you see D50 on browser ?  Lets have a look into the future :

So what happens when **CLIENT** (browser) parses the javascripts?

Browser will execute

```
var jvalue = form1.code1.value;
```

line and set jvalue to D50 and of course when Browser encounters

```
<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>
```

It will run it and show the value of jvalue **ON THE CLIENT** which is **D50**..

All this will happen on Client computer not on Server.

So this will happen in near future, not yet....

Now back to your php file

```
//$c = 'D50';    // lets ignore this   

$c = $abc;                                    // php runs this on server. 

// guess what now $c is '<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>'     

// then php tries to run this:

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmycode where code='$c';");
```

Now your query became really interesting :

```
SELECT * FROM tblmycode where code='<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>';
```

I hope you understand now what is happening...

PS: mysql interface  is deprecated use mysqli or PDO please...

Comment: `$abc` will be `<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>`, you're not stripping the tags anywhere

Comment: how do we do that...?

Comment: Do what? `strip_tags()`?

Comment: i'm stuck here...

IF I REPLACE `$c = 'D50';` PHP SQL RECOGNIZE AND RECORD DISPLAY/ NO PROBLEM HERE

IF I REPLACE `$c = $abc;` DATA NOT FOUND, I TRIED TRIM ALSO. BUT `ECHO $abc;` its print as D50

Comment: `echo strip_tags(%abc);` print AS document.write(jvalue)   and `echo %abc;` print AS D50, i want to make D50

Comment: @user2235050 strip tags warning was for me not you... I forgot to strip the tags when writing the answer... So it is not about you or your script... Sorry for the confusion though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how backend and frontend works.

Your PHP first generates the HTML server-side, sends it to the user which then runs the it in the browser and executes the Javascript.

So when you write this:

```
$abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"
```

`$abc` will **not** be the result of your JavaScript. It will literally be a string containing `<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>`.

So your approach is totally wrong - you can't pass variables like that to PHP!

What you need to do is send the field values to the server so they can be processed by your script.

Read some tutorials like [this one](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html).

Comment: thank you MMM, i want to make this form without submit, when user enter data in inputbox data should display in another textbox same form. is it possible to convert `$abc` to php data text string()

Comment: You don't understand: you cannot read JavaScript variables or a result of JavaScript code in PHP. Period! If you want to make some text appear from one field in a another field, **use JavaScript**. JavaScript is used for **client-side** programming, PHP is used for **server-side** programming. You use PHP to render a HTML page. It gets run on the **server**, not the user's browser.

Comment: Also, it is technically impossible to make this work without submitting the data. You have to send something to the server if you want to use that value in PHP. There is absolutely no way around it.

Comment: I GOT IT, THANK YOU, JUST 1 MORE QUESTION IS IT POSSIBLE IN PHP AJAX LIKE http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp HOW TO MAKE IN AJAX

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. If you're asking how to use AJAX, I cannot help you as you simply need to learn it. But first you should learn about the principles of web development and the distinction between back-end and front-end. Don't dive into PHP, JavaScript, SQL, AJAX etc. without that knowledge, because you will make terrible websites.

Comment: When a user types a character in the input field above, the function "showResult()" is executed. The function is triggered by the "onkeyup" event: